# Error in configuration wizard of Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, installation, 2016

I have installed sharepoint 2016 on windows server 2012 R2, installation is completed successful. but in configuration wizards it shows wired errors like in screen shot.

after so many uninstall and install it shows following error  at different different time.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update...

after installation of  SharePoint Server 2016 RC  update, it worked perfectly.
[Download Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50737)

[image]